# How to find the number of cores which are currently being utilized by Windows Service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I have created a multi threaded application which is running via Windows Services. Earlier there were 2 cores in my system which I have increased to 6 cores. Even after increasing the number of cores the performance of my application is not optimized
I tried threads as well as task to achieve multi threading in my application but there is no significant difference in performance of my application.
How can I find the numbers of threads and cores running or being utilized in my system by my application , so that I can know that are all my cores being utilized or not?

Comment: You are asking for something more specific than [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount)?

Comment: "there is no significant difference in performance of my application." - first, have you confirmed that CPU is the bottleneck? If your problem is e.g. I/O bound it doesn't matter how many cores are available to it.

Comment: Environment.ProcessorCount tells the no of cores not the no os cores being utilized

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the scheduler of the OS.  Your Windows Service is not the only one running on the machine.  The OS decides how to allocate CPU time to all threads that need to run.

If you want to make your application more "multi-core-friendly", you need to share more details about it and what it does.